# Mean value estimation for complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f $ be holomorphic in a region $ U $.

How can I prove that $$ |f\left(w_{1}\right)-f\left(w_{2}\right)|\leq|w_{1}-w_{2}|\cdot\max\left\{ f'\left(z\right):z\in U\right\}  $$

I know this can be easily deduced from the fundemental theorem of complex analysis, but this is just the beggining of the course, and we have'nt prove yet that holomorphic function is also a $C^1 $ function, so basically I cannot use the fact that $ f' $ is continuous, and therefore cannot use the fundemental theorem.

(Also, I cannot use the fact the holomorphic function is analytic function ofcourse).

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot the absolute value on $f'$.  Just use the mean-value inequality from real analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define$$\begin{array}{rccc}\gamma\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&t&\mapsto&(1-t)w_1+tw_2\end{array}$$and let $\hat f=f\circ\gamma$. By the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions), there is come $c\in[0,1]$ such that$$\left|\hat f(1)-\hat f(0)\right|\leqslant\left|\hat f'(c)\right|.\tag1$$But $\hat f(0)=f(w_1)$, $\hat f(1)=f(w_2)$, and, since $\hat f'=(f'\circ\gamma).\gamma'$ and since$$(\forall t\in[0,1]):\gamma'(t)=w_2-w_1,$$ you deduce from $(1)$ that\begin{align}|f(w_2)-f(w_1)|&\leqslant|w_2-w_1|.\max\{|f'(z)|\mid z\in\gamma([0,1])\}\\&\leqslant|w_2-w_1|.\max\{|f'(z)|\mid z\in U\}.\end{align}

Comment: What if  the image $ \gamma\left([0,1]\right) $ is not contained in $ U $? (you suggested a linear function, but what if $U $ is not convex ?

Comment: If $U$ is not convex, then the statement is false.

Comment: How can I prove directly that there exists $ \theta $ such that $ |f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)|\leq|f'\left(\theta\right)||x-y| $ for $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C} $ ? In the link you gave for wikipedia there is no proof, and I found proof for general $ n $ but it is very complicated (13 pages)

Comment: Why do you say that? That Wikipedia page *has* a proof of the theorem.